# How to replace a pattern after specific character in logstash message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a message like this :

```
`The is my sample HMAC message`HMAC HMAC HMAC
```

I want to replace this to :

```
`The is my sample HMAC message`
```

I have tried below code but it replaces all occurrences of HMAC:

```
mutate {
                    gsub => [ "message", "HMAC", "" ]
                  }
```

I only want the pattern to be replaced after `.
How can I achieve this in logstash using gsub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grok.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "`%{DATA:my_field_name}`" }
  }
}
```

the output will be:

```
{
  "my_field_name": "The is my sample HMAC message"
}
```

To test you can use kibana grok debugger (see screenshot)
or you can use https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result
[image]

> EDIT: You can create a new field with quotes intact.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "my_new_field" => "`%{[my_field_name]}`" }
}
```

Comment: This will work fine ..But I am not allowed to change name of the field ..It has to be kept as message only.  Hence i wanted to substitute using gsub

Comment: You can use `rename` the change the field name in `mutate` filter. `rename => {"old_field_name" => "new_field_name"}`

Comment: Thanks Musab.. This has worked .. just one more query.  by using this grok the quotes` which a part of message are getting replaced as well.. How can keep the quotes intact. I mean the Message should look like :  `The is my sample HMAC message`