# How can we remove a pattern after specific character in logstash message using gsub

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, mutate

Sample message :

```
13-12-2022 `ACTIVITY-LOG` 20108 `The is my sample HMAC message`HMAC HMAC HMAC
```

I want to replace this to :

```
13-12-2022 `ACTIVITY-LOG` 20108 `The is my sample HMAC message`
```

I have tried below code but it replaces all occurrences of HMAC:

```
mutate {
                    gsub => [ "message", "HMAC", "" ]
                  }
```

I only want the pattern to be removed when it comes immediately after `.
How can I achieve this in logstash using gsub?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a pattern after specific character in logstash message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319666/how-to-replace-a-pattern-after-specific-character-in-logstash-message)

Comment: No this is not solving the issue..

Comment: Why you are posting same question again ? If it is not woked then why did you marked answer as solution ?

Comment: The requirements are different for both questions . The solution has worked for the specific case but i want to remove the pattern using global substitute .